# glob "one or more" in Python

Tags: python, glob

I need to get all text files with numeric names: `1.txt, 2.txt, 13.txt`
Is it possible to do with `glob`?

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob('[0-9].txt'):
    print(file)
```

Does not return 13.txt.
And there seems to be no regex's one or more `+` operator.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that `glob()` is meant to be that customisable.  You might want to try `os.listdir()` instead:

```
import os,re
for f in os.listdir("/path/to/dir"):
    if re.match(r"^\d+\.txt$", f):
        print(f)
```

Comment: Heh.  My bad.  Too much time in Django-land.

Answer (score 3):

From [TFM](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html):

> No tilde expansion is done, but *, ?, and character ranges expressed
>   with [] will be correctly matched

So, no, there are no `+` operators as in regex.  You can use `glob` as a first-pass (as in `glob('*.txt')`), and filter it further with `regex`.